# Fixing Bootstrap Affix to near standing column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix, scrollspy

Appreciate if you can help me. I have several bootstrap rows, and one of them contain 2 columns - left for the scrollable text, and right for the description fixed by affix. Right column must be shown when I scroll down to the top of left column and hide when left column is over. I tried to make it work that way, but it didn't work out. Now affix fixed to the body (and not to the top and bottom borders of parent block like I wanted). What am I doing wrong? (except me speaking English :) )

index.html:

```
...
<body data-spy="scroll">
...
    <div class="chapter">
        <div class="row" data-target="#myScrollSpy">
            <div class="col-md-5" >
                my precious scrollable text
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" id="myScrollSpy">
               <div id="myAffix">
                   my not so good working affix
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
...
    <script>
    $('#myAffix').affix({
              offset: {
                top: 100,
                bottom: 100
              }
            });
    </script>
...
</body>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.affix {
    top: 150px;
  width: 80%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .affix {
  }         
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .affix-bottom {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it turns out that better decision is to forget about affix and use stickyfill - https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill